# Ubuntu Java XML FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, xml, file, exception, ubuntu

I keep getting this error from my java application...

```
[00:00:01]: java.io.FileNotFoundException: ./data/world/xml/woodcutting/Trees.xml (No such file or directory)
[00:00:01]:     at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
[00:00:01]:     at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:137)
[00:00:01]:     at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:96)
[00:00:01]:     at com.rs2.world.XMLManager.load(XMLManager.java:61)
[00:00:01]:     at com.rs2.GameEngine.main(GameEngine.java:64)
```

This error only shows when I use the Ubuntu operating system. I never get this error when I use windows.

Could someone please tell me how to fix this problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Linux is case sensitive whereas Windows is not. Does the case of the path you've written above exactly match the real case (e.g. is it trees.xml rather than Trees.xml)?

Comment: In general the dot (.) at the beginning of the path points to the directory the JVM is started in... intended?

Comment: Thanks, It was a case sensitive issue.